# What development environment is required to target `C++ 2008 Redistributable`?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, winapi

Last week I inherited a legacy unmanaged C++ application.

Unfortunately the project settings are not 100% reliable, and there is no documentation.  What I do know is that the product was deployed with *Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable x86*.

My question is: **what combination of IDE, SDK, and Platform ToolSet would you recommend using?**

Unfortunately I haven't worked with the *Windows SDK* before, and the *Platform ToolSet* option is new to me.  To make matters worse, I haven't written a line of C++ code in eight years!  So... any feedback you can provide would be greatly appreciated :D

KNOWNS

- **Client Operating System**

  - Windows 2008 R2
- **C++ Redistributable**

  - *Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable x86* is deployed in production
- **Integrated Development Environment** (IDE)

  - I would prefer to use *Visual Studio 2012* (we also have: Visual Studio 2008, 2010, 2012)

UNKNOWNS

- **Platform ToolSet**

  - Can I use VS2012 and target the v90 platform, or is it more stable to simply use VS2008?
- **Windows SDK**

  - Which [version of the Windows SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK#Versions%20Windows%20SDK) should I install on the development machine if the client is using *Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable x86* in production?

Comment: what do you mean by " the current project settings are not 100% reliable"?

Comment: i'd go with the oldest supported version, unless you plan on upgrading a lot of nuts and bolts

Comment: @ZDeslav "the current project settings are not 100% reliable" = the product is from well before my time, and I have reason to believe that other developers have changed the `project configuration` without fully understanding what they are doing.

Comment: @sehe: "i'd go with the oldest supported version" does this mean IDE=`Visual Studio 2008` + SDK=`Windows Server 2008 & .NET 3.5 SDK (v6.1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would *start* by trying to get the project to compile successfully in Visual Studio 2008, since you mentioned you already have that available.

I wouldn't bother trying to install another version of the Windows SDK (one comes bundled with VS 2008) *unless* you can't get the project to compile successfully in an out-of-the-box install of VS 2008. If not and you do want to try installing another version of the SDK, I would opt for [version 7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279), the one that targets Windows 7.

There is unlikely to be any advantage in using version 6.1 of the SDK; new versions might add new features, but they generally retain backwards compatibility with the old versions. I would *not*, however, install any version of the Windows 8 SDK because that might end up confusing you as the developer.

Once you get everything up and going on VS 2008, you could try switching over to VS 2012 if you'd prefer to use it. (I still can't get used to the UI, but apparently *someone* likes it.) As you point out in the question, the easiest way of making this work correctly would be to target "v90", which is VS 2008 (set using the Platform Toolset option). That will basically allow you to use the VS 2012 shell for editing purposes, but the VS 2008 compiler and headers for builds. You won't get any of the C++11 features introduced with VS 2012, however, because you're not using the new version of the compiler; you'll be stuck with what was supported back in VS 2008.

Comment: @CodyGrey – If you don’t mind, I have a supplementary question. There are at least three different ways to supply the compiler with location of dependencies (e.g. libraries and header files) **1** environment variables (e.g. %lib% and %include%) **2**  `Configuration Properties=>VC++ Directories` and **3**  `Configuration Properties=>…=>Additional Include Directories`… what is the recommended approach when defining the location of the Windows SDK? The reason why I ask is the developer machine I was given already has multiple SDKs installed (v5.0, v6.0A, v7.0A, v7.1A, v8.0, v8.0A).

Comment: @Pressacco Hmm, I don't know. I was hoping you weren't using a machine that already had everything installed. Truth is, I'd make sure all of them were set properly. Generally, number 2 is what you'd configure though. Number 3 (Additional Include Directories) is generally not intended for such basic things as the Windows SDK, but libraries that are used only on a handful of individual projects. I don't ever change my environment variables; I always just use the latest version of the SDK I have installed. The Windows headers use conditional compilation well to enable downstream targeting.

Comment: @CodyGrey - Thank you for taking the time to reply to my inquiry.  Your thoughts/comments are much appreciated :D